# Microsoft Graph's createUploadSession, Content-Range Header error

Tags: javascript, fetch, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, http-content-range

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API's `createUploadSession` endpoint with the JavaScript SDK and attempting to test the upload with a small file that's just over 3MB. Whenever send a `PUT` request, I receive the following error response:

```
{
  "error": {
     "code": "InvalidContentRangeHeader",
     "message": "Invalid Content-Range header."
  }
}
```

I'm trying to send over the whole file at once, so here's what the request looks like:

```js
  const uploadSession = await client
    .api(`/me/messages/${messageId}/attachments/createUploadSession`)
    .version('beta')
    .post({
      AttachmentItem: {
        attachmentType: 'file',
        name: attachment.name,
        size: attachment.size,
      },
    });

  const res = await fetch(uploadSession.uploadUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Range': `bytes 0-${attachment.size - 1}/${attachment.size}`,
      'Content-Length': attachment.size,
    },
    body: attachment.contentBytes,
  });

  const json = await res.json();
  return json;
```

Is there anything here that I'm missing? If I understand correctly giving the complete range should pass along the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be outdated, since you were using the beta version, and UploadSessions are now part of the core functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments.

Anyway, I still decided to share my working implementation of this in JS (TypeScript, to be more correct), since most of questions on this topic are for `C#`.

I didn't try to upload the whole file at once after creating the `uploadSession` (though the docs state it's possible), but decided to `PUT` the whole stuff in 4MB chunks as they recommend.

```
const BYTE_RANGE = 4e6

...

// Send large attachments using an uploadSession
private async _uploadLargeAttachments(
    attachments: IMSLargeFileAttachment[],
    messageId: string,
    clientInstance: Client
): Promise<string[]> {
    return Promise.all(
        attachments.map(async (attachment) => {
            const { attachmentType, name, size } = attachment
            const uploadSession: UploadSession = await clientInstance
                .api(`/me/messages/${messageId}/attachments/createUploadSession`)
                .post({
                    AttachmentItem: { attachmentType, name, size },
                })

                if (!uploadSession.uploadUrl) {
                    // You may also want to throw an error here
                    return null
                }

            const fragmentsTotal = Math.ceil(size / BYTE_RANGE)
            let i = 0
            let bytesRemaining = size

            while (i < fragmentsTotal) {
                const step = (i + 1) * BYTE_RANGE
                const from = i * BYTE_RANGE
                const to = bytesRemaining > BYTE_RANGE ? step - 1 : size - 1
                bytesRemaining = Math.max(size - step, 0)

                const res = await fetch(uploadSession.uploadUrl, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                        'Content-Length': `${to - from + 1}`,
                        'Content-Range': `bytes ${from}-${to}/${size}`,
                    },
                    body: attachment.body.slice(from, to + 1), // the 2nd slice arg is not inclusive
                })

                // The final response should have the 'Location' header with a long URL,
                // from which you can extract the attachment ID
                if (res.status === 201 && res.headers.has('Location')) {
                    return res.headers.get('Location')
                }
                i++
            }
        }).filter((it) => Boolean(it))
    )
}
```

Hope this helps anyone struggling with this as I was to reach their goal faster.